# Configure `git pull` to use --ff and `git merge` to use --no-ff

Tags: git

I would like `git merge` to default to `--no-ff` and `git pull` to use `--ff` when it merges the fetched branch.

Is there a way to configure git to do this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest setting `merge.ff=false` and using `git pull --rebase` to get new changes.

If you have no local commits, it will give the same result as `git pull`, but without doing a merge.

If you do have some local commits it will rebase those, avoiding the usually unwanted merge commit.

This way you make sure you get a merge commit for all explicit merges, and avoid the noise of implicit merge commits, which is usually exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since Git 2.0 you can set `merge.ff=false` and `pull.ff=only` to achieve the desired result.